# ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0 while trying to obtain image features using MobileNet

Tags: python, keras, image-processing, deep-learning, feature-extraction

I wanted to use MobileNet to obtain features of all images present in a dataset. But the error mentioned keeps popping up.

The full code that produced the error is:

`

```
from keras.applications import MobileNet
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Model
from keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input

# Load the MobileNet model
base_model = MobileNet(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# Define the data generator
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

# Create the data generator for the custom dataset
image_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        'C:/Users/mahit/OneDrive/Pictures/Desktop/DATA AND VIDEOS//16k_images',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=1,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=False)

# Obtain the image features
image_features = base_model.predict(image_generator, 16042)

# Save the image features to a file
np.save('mobilenet_image_features.npy', image_features)
```

`

The full error is as follows:

[image]

I wanted to obtain the image features and save it in a .npy file. But this error keeps coming up.

Comment: Go to the terminal, run `DIR "C:/Users/mahit/OneDrive/Pictures/Desktop/DATA AND VIDEOS//16k_images"` and see if you get a list of images. I have the feeling that the forward slashes (and maybe the double slash in  `VIDEOS//16k_images`) are causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

"Sequence has length zero" indicates that there is no data provided by the data loader. This is usually due to issues with the provided path, for which `flow_from_directory` fails silently.

One way to confirm is as @Idavid suggested in their comment, but either way you can try any of the options suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/how-should-i-write-a-windows-path-in-a-python-string-literal).